# How to fetch core data on background thread, read results on main thread synchronously?

Tags: ios, core-data

If I have 100,000 entities in a core data store, how could I get access to/load/fetch all 100,000 in a background thread, and once loaded/fetched access the properties of these entities on the main thread/other threads? (For example, showing the items in a UICollectionView)  I will be using batching to avoid loading all 100,000 into memory - but I will need to know exactly how many there are after the initial load.

Something like this:

```
// The load occurs on a background thread
[self loadCoreData: ^{
    // Once loaded, dispatch back onto the main thread to get the number of
    // entities, or I could do something like [self getEntityMatchingProperties:...]
    // etc. the point being it accesses entity information that has been loaded but
    // on a different thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.title = [self getNumberOfCoreDataEntities];
    });
}];
```

Edit: another (more exact example):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // The load occurs on a background thread
    [self loadCoreData: ^{
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self numberOfItemsLoadedFromCoreData];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    Entity *entity = [self getItemLoadedFromCoreDataAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ...
}
```

In the second example I'm trying to use a `NSFetchedResultsController` I suppose - are there any full examples of this type of approach? All of them I see deal with snippets doing the fetch with the main context - which would do the work on the main thread.

Comment: I'm rusty, but your snippet appears to be simply running getNumberOfCoreDataEntities on the main thread which seems to defeat the purpose.  I feel like you should be making that call before you dispatch back to main thread. i.e. Store the result of that call in a variable and then assign the variable to self.title on the main thread.

Comment: @ghostatron I can understand that point of view, sure.  That was a bad example maybe.  Consider the example where on a view being loaded I'd like to start a long running load/fetch operation.  Then later in an entirely different method I'd like to access the number of core data entities, i.e. in a "collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection" call, etc.

Comment: If that was just a simplified example, then I apologize. As for passing managed objects across thread boundaries, I think that is a fundamental no-go. You can create your own classes to store the values and pass those across, or you can refetch using the managed object ID (which is thread safe).

Comment: As a random toss in, in case you haven't seen them yet.  There are methods along the lines of "perform" and "performAndWait" that help deal with thread issues.  I remember using those heavily in my former life. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be reinventing `NSFetchedResultsController`, which will handle everything you need here. You're making things unnecessarily hard for yourself. This is a common need, and Apple's got you covered. Create the `NSFetchedResultsController` with your fetch request, and implement your collection view methods to ask it for objects based on index path. As a bonus, `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods can be used to update your collection view if the underlying data changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am in the process of mocking something up, but what `ManagedObjectContext` do I pass to the `NSFetchedResultsController`?  If it's the main context, won't that block the UI as the fetch occurs? In my app it's a potentially seconds long fetch, definitely not desired to just freeze there.

Comment: It's made for use with the UI, so you'd normally use the main context. It can also cache data on its own to improve performance, and it's smart enough to not load every object into memory at once.